# Correct syntax for INNER JOIN in Access SQL?

Tags: sql, asp.net, ms-access

There's an error in join syntax. And I can't find it at all.

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="fav_data" runat="server" DataFile="~/paperhome_data.accdb"
                                SelectCommand="INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM [music_data] [music_junc] ON [music_d_id].[music_data]=[music_d_id].[music_junc]) WHERE ([profile_id] = 2)"></asp:AccessDataSource>
                            <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="2" Name="profile_id" Type="Boolean" />
                    </SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy to guess what you are trying to, but it could be something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM [music_data] INNER JOIN [music_junc] ON [music_data].[music_d_id]=[music_junc].[music_d_id]) WHERE ([profile_id] = 2)"
```

It seems as you really need to read up on SQL syntax. You will get nowhere trying to write SQL in the wild.

Comment: That did it, had to add an opening bracket after FROM. :)

Comment: Oops, sorry, but try to remove the closing bracket instead.

Comment: Works both ways. Interesting. :/